# Good way to measure execution time along with count using prometheus metric

Tags: spring-boot, prometheus, grafana

Our springboot based service receives events through HTTP calls and then forwards them to  GCP pub-sub to be processed through a listener, we wanted to measure the total time to process the event.

One approach I was thinking of was using histograms to track the processing times and use labels for the type of events, processing results, etc.

Would have liked to track the actual time the event was received and when it was picked up by the listener for processing but I think using labels for such data would be a bad practice.

Am I on the right track or is there are better ways to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Metric will not allow you "to track the actual time the event was received...", and they are not supposed to. Metrics are for aggregated data, like how many requests were processed, and how mush did it take time in total (with subsequent estimation of average time taken per request based on increase in time).

If this level of granularity is acceptable for your case - histograms are a way to go.

If you need traces of actual invocation, you shouldn't use Prometheus for this; use actual solutions for tracing (like Grafana Tempo, for example) or logging solutions (like Grafana Loki, for example).